# Action bar searchview widget

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

Is there a way to increase or decrease the width of the SearchView in the Actionbar. Also can searchView widget be made center or right justified?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom view.

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(resId/view)
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

In that view you can add a relative layout for example and place the view the way you like it.
Of course the view cannot be higher then the actionbar or wider then the free space.

Comment: I have SearchView as an collapsable action view in the action bar. When search icon is pressed search view expands out but dosen't occupy the entire length of action bar. I want to avoid using custom view.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible... Good luck with it! If you find out let us know.
(Perhaps you can find a way to iterate through the views in the actionbar and find the one you are looking for and adjust the layoutparams, but i don't know if that is possible)

Comment: I guess there is no other way but to use custom view. Is it possible to collapse the SearchView in the custom view programmatically?